# Hat is obscured on flag summary page

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, flag-history

If you visit your flag summary page (profile → impact → helpful flags) you will see that icon contains a obscured hat:

> [image]

Only if your hat is large enough and placed on the left hand size from the pure user icon. Like on the picture above.

Top part of the hat can be obscured as well:

> [image]

Comment: It isn't for me. I think it is because your hat extends quite far from the border of your pic.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats obviously! There is no issue when hat fits in the icon borders. Just use another or shift it to the most left position with bigger size.